# In python is there something like updated that is to update what sorted is to sort?

Tags: python, dictionary

In python if I do the following:

```
>>> list = [ 3, 2, 1]
>>> sorted_list = k.sort()
```

Then `sorted_list` is `None` and `list` is sorted:

```
>>> sorted_list = k.sort()
>>> print list, sorted_list
[1, 2, 3] None
```

However, if I do the following:

```
>>> list = [ 3, 2, 1]
>>> sorted_list = sorted(list)
```

Then `list` remains unsorted and `sorted_list` contains a copy of the sorted list:

```
>>> print list, sorted_list
[3, 2, 1] [1, 2, 3]
```

I am wondering if there is an equivalent for the `update` function for dictionaries.

That way I could do something like this:

```
def foo(a, b, extra={}):
    bar = { 'first': a, 'second': b }
    special_function(**updated(bar, extra))
    normal_function(**bar)
```

rather than having to do something like this:

```
def foo(a, b, extra={}):
    bar = { 'first': a, 'second': b }
    special_bar = bar.copy()
    special_bar.update(extra) # [1]
    special_function(**special_bar)
    normal_function(**bar)
```

<sub>[1] Yes I realize I could simply replace these two lines with `extra.update(bar)` but let's assume I want to retain `extra` as is for later on in the function.</sub>

I realize I could implement this myself thusly:

```
def updated(old_dict, extra={}):
    new_dict = old_dict.copy()
    new_dict.update(extra)
    return new_dict
```

Or the following highly unreadable in-place statement:

```
    special_function(**(dict(bar.items()+extra.items())))
```

But I was hoping there was something built in that I could already use.

Comment: You should *not* use `dict` as a variable name.  Also beware of mutable default arguments -- better get into the habit to never use them.

Comment: Your should *not* use `dict` as a variable name, I think @SvenMarnach means :)

Comment: @MattLuongo: Thanks.  I indeed said the opposite of what I meant. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach right you are; example updated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply use the built-in `dict()`:

```
updated_dict = dict(old_dict, **extra_dict)
```

Comment: Note that this will not work if the `extra_dict` keys are not strings.

Comment: @RikPoggi: I definitely should have mentioned this.  For the use case given in the question this restriction is not relevant.

Comment: Wow. Python never fails to amaze!

Answer (score 6):

If you need non-string keys, you can use a function like that: (It is not as ugly as your "in-place" expression + it works for any number of dictionaries)

```
from itertools import chain # ← credits go to Niklas B.

def updated(*dicts):
    return dict(chain(*map(dict.items, dicts)))

updated({42: 'the answer'}, {1337: 'elite'}) # {42: 'the answer', 1337: 'elite'}
```

Otherwise Sven’s suggestion is just fine.

Edit: If you are using Python 2.7 or later, you can also use a dictionary comprehension, as Sven suggested in the comments:

```
def updated(*dicts):
    return {k: v for d in dicts for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: +1, I like this :) Although I think `sum` for list concatenation is quite ugly, maybe `itertools.chain` would be a bit cleaner. For two dicts it's just `dict(d1.items() + d2.items())` by the way, which is a bit more readable, IMO.

Comment: Using `sum()` for list concatenation is not only ugly, it will make the whole thing O(n^2).  How about using something like `{k: v for d in dicts for k, v in d.items()}`?

Comment: @SvenMarnach Actually this is a really good idea!  I am used to Python 2.6, so I do not always use Python 2.7 features...

Comment: @NiklasB. `itertools.chain` sounds like a better idea than `sum`.  It is cleaner, but in terms of performance `sum` and `chain` are very similar (slow…).  I think I prefer Sven’s dictionary comprehension. :)

Comment: @Gandaro: `chain()` (and `chain.from_iterable()`, for that matter) would both be O(n), while the `sum()` version is O(n^2).  For a larger number of dictionaries, the `sum()` version will become really slow.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really see what's wrong in using two lines, like you do:

```
new_bar = bar.copy()
new_bar.update(extra)
```

It's clean and readable.

```
>>> d = {1:2, 3:4}
>>> e = {3:9, 5:25}
>>> f = d.copy()
>>> f.update(e)
>>> d
{1: 2, 3: 4}
>>> f
{1: 2, 3: 9, 5: 25}
>>> e
{3: 9, 5: 25}
```

In three words: [**Zen of Python**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

**To be more clear:** My point is that I wouldn't replace those two lines with an `updated()` function that's not coming from the standard library.

If I was to stumble in a line of code like:

```
new_bar = updated(bar, extra)
```

I'd *have* to track that function down to see what it does. I couldn't trust that it doesn't something strange.

The OP also compared that with `sorted()`, but `sorted()` has it's reason to exist, it acts on everything that's iterable and does that with the amazing timsort. Instead what should be the behaviour of an hypothetical `updated()`? Should that maybe be a `dict` class method? It's really not clear IMHO.

Said so one could choose the OP two lines, or Sven's solution, or a dict comprehension/generator-expression, I think it's really just a matter of taste.

Comment: Hm, it's procedural style, as opposed to a functional approach like Sven's or like `merge` in Ruby: `{1=>3, 2=>4}.merge({4=>5})`, which does not mutate anything.

Comment: @Niklas: I get that, but it seems that the OP is trying to implement an `updated()` function, my point was that I wouldn't do that. I explained that better in my "updated" answer.